# How to specify a required deeply nested devDependency using package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to bump my `ws` package version [according to this commit](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io-client/commit/81374e1ff2eee5db01b7eaffe6ed22116559d42a) in order to prevent some failures I encountered as part of running `npm install` where I have a dev dependency on `browser-sync` in my project.

I looked into [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) but I don't think it applies since I'm working with devDependencies.

What I would like to happen is that when I install through npm, it uses `ws` version 0.7.1 instead of the 0.5.0 specified inside of deeply nested package.json of engine.io-client located at:

browser-sync > socket.io > engine.io > engine.io-client

Is there a simple way I can specify this in my package.json? If not, what is the proper workflow for handling something like this in a way that's maintainable without having to fork and use my own cloned repositories?